# Component cant resolve slick carousel css

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I followed documentation of react-slick step by step.

I installed both react-slick and slick-carousel but whenever I import the css i always get this error `Module not found: Can't resolve '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'`

also this error `Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to src/pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules)`

I'm using Reactjs with nextJS

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I tried it here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-6xjtu8?file=index.js] and it works well. I just removed the tilde (~) before the css imports, the same that throw you an error

Comment: Did you import in the local component or the root ?

Comment: I tried doing that but it is giving me the second error about Global css

Comment: Now it gave me this error `ExtractPluginMissingException: svg-sprite-loader exception. svg-sprite-loader in extract mode requires the corresponding plugin`

Comment: It seems that I have answered your same question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63988376/2145213